# Symfony OneToMany Persistence using entity/collection field type

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-forms

**My Problem:** I cannot get an associated Entity to save using the entity field type or collection field type.

**My Database Relations**
[image: My Database Relations]

**Database Structure Description:**

- I have a 'Usage' entity that has many 'telephone numbers' attached to
  it.
- Each 'telephone number' has one and only one region.

**What I want to Achieve**

- On my edit 'Usage' form I want to display a dropdown box for each 'telephone number' that the 'Usage' already has attached to it.
- Each dropdown box will list all the telephone numbers for that region, allowing the user to select a new telephone number

[image]

**How I want to display my Usage Form**

[image: What I want to display]

**My Controller**

- [Usage Controller](https://gist.github.com/nischalsource/e5e5ebba5a1b396cb873) 
  line 146 - 203

**My Entities**

- [Usage Entity](https://gist.github.com/nischalsource/22ab12843cb8d6523502)
- [Telephone Entity](https://gist.github.com/nischalsource/4f95b813e689d819adb9)

**Form Type**

- [UsageType - form](https://gist.github.com/nischalsource/93cf8a62dbf6c62f82b8)

**Twig Template**

- [Usage Form Page](https://gist.github.com/nischalsource/bda0ac131a1decb54c24)
  line 80 -128

**ViewTransformer**

[ObjectToArrayTransformer](https://gist.github.com/nischalsource/854e7a5fd821aad16e5a)

**My Problem:**
When I submit the form, nothing happens, the new telephone number I selected is not persisted.

Answer (score 2):

I think your problem is that in your Usage Entity, you don't cascade the persist operation. You should try this :

```
@ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Telephone", mappedBy="usage", cascade={"persist"})
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I have tried this but it doesn't change anything. What should this do?

Comment: persist : Cascades persist operations to the associated entities. Check out the [docs](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/working-with-associations.html#transitive-persistence-cascade-operations).
After the change you should clear the cache!

Comment: I have added persist to the Usage Entity relation to TelephoneNumbers. The form is submitting, however the telephone numbers are not saving. In **Symfony Profiler** I see this **Error** for the Form:  'Unable to reverse value for property path "telephoneNumbers": Could not find all matching choices for the given values'. I have added a ViewTransformer.

Comment: Can you dump the value of telephone that is being passed to the form ?

Comment: I want to say I have also tried placing my own hidden input tags and populating them using javascript OnClick of the dropdown boxes. However this solution never worked as I never could get the submitted data into a structure that the form expected. I am willing to explore this option as well.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but it seems you are trying to persist a PersistentCollection all at once. Maybe looping through this collection and persisting each one of its elements one by one would work.

Comment: Would I do that in my Controller? Between line 192 -> 196?

Comment: Also...if I changed an existing 'telephone number' for a 'Usage', how would I unset the old 'telephone number' ?

Comment: The thing is : why are there multiple numbers flushed ? Do they all have to be persisted ? Maybe you should have two properties in your entity and in your form if you want two phone numbers. If not, try to see why there are two numbers posted ...

Comment: A Usage can have oneToMany telephone_numbers. In the example I posted you, The Usage had 2 telephone_numbers. Other Usages can have zero or more 'telephone_numbers'.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78297/discussion-between-nischal-bachu-and-guillaume-fache).